# tengo una duda de como programo esto no me esta sacando el min,max,y promedio

Tags: java

Empleando un array, escribir un programa que pida al usuario
números enteros hasta que se introduzca el número 0. A continuación, calcular la media, el mínimo y el máximo de los datos introducidos. Utilice funciones independientes para: a) recibir N números enteros por teclado hasta que el usuario introduzca un 0; b) Calcule la media de los elementos de un array; c) calcule el mínimo de los elementos de un array; y d) Calcule el máximo de los elementos de un array.

```
package pkg1;
import java.util.Scanner;
        /**
 *
 * @author pepelarrave
 */
public class ej8 {
        
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado= new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero, mayor=0, menor=0, suma=0;int promedio=0;
   int lista[] =new int[100] ;
    System.out.println("dame numeros");
     numero = teclado.nextInt();
   
      while (numero>0){
         System.out.println("introduce numeros");
     numero = teclado.nextInt();
    mayor=menor=lista[0];
     
    
    if(numero==0){
        break;
    }
    else {
  for( int i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
         if(lista[i]>mayor){
             mayor=lista[i];
         }
         
    
             if(lista[i]<menor){
                 menor=lista[i];
             }
         
              
             }
             
                     
   
     for(int i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
         suma= lista[i]+suma;
                     
                     
               
     }
  }
      }
     promedio=suma/lista.length;
     System.out.println("El numero mayor es:" +mayor);
     System.out.println("El numero menor es:" +menor);
     System.out.println("La suma es:" +suma);  
     
}
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: cuando introduzco 0 que es cuando se debería de terminar el programa me aparece que el max, min,suma y promedio es 0

Comment: Estás seteando en `0` el mayor y menor; los números que ingresas siempre van a la posición `0` del array `lista`. Para que funcione bien, deberías almacenar cada valor ingresado en una posición diferente del array y cambiar el valor de máximo y mínimo diferente de `0`.

Comment: como haría eso?

Answer (score 1):

Como dije en el comentario, debes almacenar en posiciones diferentes del array:

```
while (numero>0){
    System.out.println("introduce numeros");
    numero = teclado.nextInt();
    lista[indice] = numero;//Aquí agregas en la posición indice el valor introducido.
    indice += 1;//Aumentas en 1 el indice.
        
    if(numero==0){
        break;
    }
 }
```

El código completo quedaría:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado= new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero = 1, mayor=0, menor=0, suma=0;int promedio=0;
        int lista[] =new int[100] ;
        int indice = 0;
        
        while (numero>0){
            System.out.println("introduce numeros");
            numero = teclado.nextInt();
            lista[indice] = numero;
            indice += 1;
        
            if(numero==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        
        for( int i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
             if(lista[i]>mayor){
                 mayor=lista[i];
             }
         
             if(lista[i]<menor){
                 menor=lista[i];
             }
        }
   
         for(int i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
             suma= lista[i]+suma;
         }

     promedio=suma/lista.length;
     System.out.println("El numero mayor es:" +mayor);
     System.out.println("El numero menor es:" +menor);
     System.out.println("La suma es:" +suma);  
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Estas asumiendo que siempre se ingresaran los 100 números al momento de calcular el promedio, ahi seria mejor dividir entre el indice. Igualmente al momento de encontrar el mayor, no tiene caso recorrer todo una lista que posiblemente este la mitad vacia. Limitarlo al Indice es mucho mejor.

Comment: @Gervera no estoy asumiendo, es el código original de la pregunta.